# "what kind of" vs "the kind"

Tags: word-choice

Which one is correct? If both, what is the difference?

1. Could you tell us what kind of noise does it give off?
2. Could you tell us the kind of noise it gives off?

Comment: Can you please give full sentences? It will help you receive better answers.

Comment: "Could you tell us what/the kind of noise it gives off?" or simply "What kind of noise does it give off?"

Comment: Tell us the kind of noise...vs Tell us what kind of noise -  I would vote for the second.

Comment: The first is ungrammatical, but the reason is that it should be << (1') Could you tell us what kind of noise it gives off? >> But Kate's third suggestion sounds far more natural. As does 'How does it sound?' / 'What does it sound like?'

Comment: *I know **the** answer you seek!* OR *I know **what** answer you seek!* In such contexts, ***what*** (or ***which***) just looks like another kind of "determiner" that doesn't really mean anything different to the definite article anyway. Note that the syntax of the containing utterance is different though - there's an unstated ***that*** after ***answer*** in the first version, but that syntactic role is already implied by ***what*** in the second version, so it can't be "added again".

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that one is a *direct question* and the other an *indirect question*.

---

You can 'ask' for something in the form of a question, or you can demand it using a statement, for example:

- What is the time? (question)
- Tell me the time! (demand)

Of course, you can make a demand polite by turning it into a question, for example:

- *Please could you* tell me the time?

These are all *direct questions*. Your example 2 is a direct question - the question is '*could you tell us*'.

---

Your example 1 is an *indirect question*. It technically asks two questions - "could you tell us" and "what kind of noise?". It is idiomatic and is essentially asking a question if it is possible to answer another question.

You could make it a direct question by using a comma to separate them:

> Could you tell us, what kind of noise does it give off?